# Как изменить заголовок и исполнителя аудиозаписи в telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot

Обрисую проблему:

У меня есть telegram бот. Мне нужно отправить аудиофайл пользователю бота через метод ***sendAudio***, причем этот аудиофайл доступен по ссылке. Однако этот аудиофайл уже имеет исполнителя и название. Я пытаюсь добавить параметры ***title*** и ***performer***, однако без толку. Исполнитель и название прежние.

Нужно используя средства node.js и telegram api решить эту проблему, если возможно без скачивания файла на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

**Это невозможно**, если аудиофайл уже присутствует на серверах телеграма, а в случае с *URL* или *file_id* файл уже либо есть на серверах, либо сначала загружается по переданной ссылке, а уже затем выполняется метод ***sendAudio***.

> When using ***file_id***, it is just sending a file as present in Telegram
>   servers, so ***duration***, ***performer*** and ***title*** are taken from that file and
>   not from the params (file can't be modified at all, not even the
>   metadata). Something similar happens with ***URL***, those fields are taken
>   from the ***URL***. ([@BotSupport](https://telegram.me/botsupport))

Передавать эти параметры имеет смысл только в том случае, если в методе sendAudio в качестве параметра передавать непосредственно сам файл - [*InputFile*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile).

> ***InputFile***
>   This object represents the contents of a file to be
>   uploaded. Must be posted using multipart/form-data in the usual way
>   that files are uploaded via the browser.

В этом случае можно будет установить исполнителя (***performer***), длительность (***duration***) и заголовок (***title***).